# How do I update a column by parameter in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I'm working with EntityFramework and I need to update a record. My update function has 3 parameters: `PK` (the identifier), `name` the name of the column and `newValue` the new value.

Now what I want to be able to do is pass the column which value has to change to the method and change it.

Example:
If I pass `1, "Description", "NewValue"` to the update function I want the row with `Id 1` to have its `Description` value change to `NewValue`

Comment: Ok ask again, breathe. Now clearly state what you want

Comment: Are you asking how to update a field when you have a string value equal to the name of the field? IE I pass in `update(objectInstance, "somefield", value)` and then you update like so `objectInstance.someField = value;`...

also you cannot update the primary key reliably in the EF

Comment: Yes @TheNorthWes, the pk help me to specific the object.

Comment: Then what you are really asking is how do I use what is called **Reflection**

Comment: Thanks @TheNorthWes I find document in internet and i solved it.